# Objective - C direct initialization (For Cocos2D style actions)

Tags: objective-c, initialization, autorelease, dealloc, action

I have a class with initialization as follows:

```
@implementation MyClass
+(id) initializeMyClass
{
    return [[[self alloc] initMyClass] autorelease];
}

-(id) initMyClass
{
    if (([self = [super init]))
    {
    }
    return self;
}

-(void) dealloc
{
    NSLog(@"Deallocating");//I also used CCLOG instead.
    [super dealloc];
}
@end
```

I initialize this class in another class without an object:

`[MyClass initializeMyClass];`

This works fine but the MyClass' dealloc method is not called and crashes since some resources are not freed.

This is totally puzzling and can't find anything online.
If anyone would suggest a solution or an alternative method, i'd really appreciate it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

if you need to initialize your MyClass into another class then you should write like

```
@implementation MyClass
+(id) initializeMyClass
{
    return [[[self alloc] initMyClass] retain];
}

-(id) initMyClass
{
    if (([self = [super init]))
    {
    }
    return self;
}

-(void) dealloc
{
    NSLog(@"Deallocating");//I also used CCLOG instead.
    [super dealloc];
}
@end
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The problem seems to persist though. The dealloc doesn't seem to be called even when released.

Comment: Only if i pass the initialized pointer to an object:                (id object = [MyClass initializeMyClass]) and call dealloc:    ([object dealloc]) does it actually get deallocated.

Comment: if you use retain or alloc then you are the responsible to release it by sending the [object release]; message...

Comment: Someone just pointed out a mistake. I was using an object which retains the class in my actual implementation. Something similar to how NSArray retains objects added to it. Thanks for your help.